# How to change the storage folder location of box.com 's Box Sync on Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, file-location, box.com

Currently it is stored in user folder as below snapshot. How can I change that i.e. I want to store my box.com files on drive D instead of system drive C which may slow down my OS.

So how can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not so easy as it should be.
You have to uninstall Box Sync, change a registry key, and install it again.

You can get more info [here](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/200852947-Can-An-Admin-Change-the-Default-Folder-Location-for-Box-Sync-).

[image]

Comment: instead of a link, post the information here.

Comment: Yeah, why don't you share us directly what it is so as to be fully get accepted ^^

Answer (score 8):

There is another way to do this as well. It is a bit more technical but it's working without issues. I am syncing all my files from an external USB drive.

The information can be found [here](http://diy.appdetector.com/change-default-folder-location-box-sync-external-drive-fixed/), but in a nutshell:

Stop Box Sync.

Edit the Box Sync database. On Windows this file is located at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Box Sync\sync.db`.

If you open the database you will see a table called preferences and the value to be changed is sync_directory_path. Update with the path where you want your files to be downloaded.

Start Box Sync.

At this step it will use the new location and it will download all your file from the cloud.

If you copy or move the contents of the original folder (by default `%USERPROFILE%\Box Sync`) to the new folder (e.g. `D:\Box`) before starting Box Sync it will not be necessary for the files you had previously synchronised to be downloaded again.

Comment: +1 much easier than the accepted solution and works, you need to have a SQL-lite database editor instralled though, I use SQLiteStudio

Comment: I feel this should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another great way to do so would be using Symbolic Links. In short, a symbolic link tricks the operating system into thinking the file resides in one location, when in reality it resides in another. I personally use a symbolic link in my Box Sync folder that points to my flash drive. That way I can sync whenever I plop the drive back in.

Here is a download that makes it easy to create symbolic links. http://lifehacker.com/5530931/link-shell-extension-creates-windows-symlinks-with-ease

Comment: I would suggest using `mklink /d` instead because it's an official Windows component.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution so far:

stop sync, logout and exit application.

delete contents of `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Box Sync` (some files were in use, but this didn't affect the change)

start sync, before logging in, click link at bottom to change the path.

Comment: Although this works to change the path, the final folder name in this solution must still be "Box Sync"